# Attribute must be the same length as the vector

Tags: r

I am trying to run in this program but am getting an error.

```
DinosaurBBQRibs <- read.table(file.choose(),sep=',')
names(DinosaurBBQRibs) <- c('City','State','Price')
```

> Error in names(DinosaurBBQRibs) <- c("City", "State", "Price") :
> 'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: look at the `dim(DinosaurBBQRibs)` before setting names, you have only one column, are you sure the values are comma-separated?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data frame, but what I guess is that your data frame (DinosaurBBQRibs) has more than or less than 3 columns. That's why when you want to assign a vector of 3 names to it, R gives you such an error. Please check the dimensions of your data frame first and based on the number of columns you have, use the appropriate number of names to assign to columns

As " rawr " mentioned above, if the csv file you are importing is for example semicolon-separated, then R import everything as one column and that can makes a problem for you.